# Sorting to ascending order when writing to txt file

Tags: java, compareto, file-writing

I'm wanting to write to a text file (which I've managed). However, I'm wanting to sort it by age.

My two classes are Person and List.

I've implemented  the comparable interface as follows

```
public class Person implements Comparable <Person> 

     public int compareTo(Person compareAge) 
   {


      return (this.getAge()- compareAge.getAge());
       }
```

In the same class I have a toString() method which prints the name and age e.g. David Age 49.

I've implemented a writePerson() method in my list class but I'm struggling to get it to sort by age.

Here is what I have...

```
public void writePerson()
 {

      File file = new File("the link to my extensions// personlist.txt);
      BufferedWriter bufferedFileWriter = null;

      try
      {
         bufferedFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(payrollFile));
         for (Person a : persons)
         {
            a.compareTo(a);
            bufferedFileWriter.write (a.toString());
            bufferedFileWriter.newLine();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception anException)
      {
         System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            bufferedFileWriter.close();
         }
         catch (Exception anException)
         {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
         }
      }
   }
```

This only prints the names without any order

Answer (score 1):

`a.compareTo(a);` -> here you compare these two and do nothing with the result. This compareTo method just return an int value representing if one is bigger than the other. In your case you compare A to A so you always get 0.

You need to sort your collection using that comparator. Java has a nice sorting method that takes list of Comparable items and sorts them. You can try with:

```
   Collections.sort(persons);
   for (Person a : persons)
         {           
            bufferedFileWriter.write (a.toString());
            bufferedFileWriter.newLine();
         }
```

It will leave the persons collection sorted though. If you want to have its initial state afterwards you can just copy it to a new collection before sorting.

Another way to do it is by the stream api which will be something like:

```
 for (Person a : list.stream().sorted((p1, p2)->p1.
                                   compareTo(p2)).
                                   collect(Collectors.toList()))
             {           
                bufferedFileWriter.write (a.toString());
                bufferedFileWriter.newLine();
             }
```

If that causes a memory issue because both solutions make a copy of the sorted array in the memory then you can do something like a search through the list - for example two nested loops or something but that's an overkill in my opinion

Comment: That has the side effect of the `persons` being sorted after... not sure if that's wanted.

Comment: Well first creating a stream, then collecting, then iterating is definitely overdoing it :D I'd be fine with creating a copy of the list if you find it more readable; as in `List<Person> sorted = new ArrayList<>(persons); Collections.sort(sorted); sorted.forEach(s -> { writer.write(s); writer.writeLine() } );`

Answer (score 1):

Like Veselin says, you need to still actually apply your comparation.

Two points though: 1. use try-with-resources for the Writer so you don't have to explicitly close it and 2. use a Stream for iteration.

That would make it

```
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("yourfile");
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter)) {
     persons.stream()    // create Stream
            .sorted()    // apply sorting
            .forEach(s -> writer.write(s + "\n"); // write
  }
  catch (Exception anException)
  {
     System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
  }
```

Comment: Just copying the array and doing sort() pratically does the same as stream and might be more readable. I do agree about try with resources though

Comment: `"\n"` should be `System.lineSeparator()` unless you want to specifically exclude Windows as a target platform. Better still, use `PrintWriter.println()`.